# Best practice: Variables, Functions and Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am using Sublime and Arduino to program a Barometer (MS5611). But what is the best practice to store variables that is only used as temporary storage inside a specific function:

1) Create private variables in my header file for all variables used?

2) Create the variables inside the functions where they are used?

What takes most processing power and memory usage - (1) create them once as private variables and change the content with the functions, or (2) create the variables each time I call a function?

Comment: If you have functions which are to be used only in a single function, then define them as local variables in the function. The stack space used by the function will be increased, but it's only temporary while the function is executing, and adding that extra stack space will not impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

Always declare them inside the function. This improves readability as it shows the intent behind the declaration. Also it lowers the chance for mistakes.

Wherever possible as "const", e.g.

```
uint16_t sample_it() {
    const uint16_t sample = analogRead(...);
    const uint16_t result = do_somehting(sample);
    return result;
}
```

Almost for the same reasons but this also gives the compiler more optimization options.

If and how variables are allocated is up to the compiler and its optimizer. Unless you have ***very*** tight performance constraints chances are that the compiler will optimize much better than you would. Actually using global variables instead will sometimes slow down your code. Of course you might avoid allocation. However you will pay by additional storage instructions. On the other hand the "allocation" might get optimized away and then your global variables code becomes slower than the local variables code.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Most of the "variables" are actually constants in their scope. So they should be declared constant. This allows for significant optimization by the compiler.

Comment: I agree with the fact that you should `const` any variables that doesn't change and initialize it right away with a *definitive* value, but in your exemple, your constants will change over time (every time you call the function) and that's forbidden :)

Comment: No, this is NOT forbidden. It compiles and behaves as expected. const just states that it is constant within the scope of the function. Whenever the function is called the constants are reinitialized.

Comment: Back on even keel Udo. The const is scoped to the method body. Further tips here: https://learn.adafruit.com/memories-of-an-arduino/

Answer (score 0):

depends on your sample rate, meaning how many times calls the function to save the data?
In any case, it is important to also take into account how empty the memory once you've collected and processed the data, in any case if you do not have a lot of variables, but you have to handle more functions that can use it is best to set them globally.
At least, I do so in my projects, and I have never had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid using global variables as they are allocated from the available heap RAM and exist (take up space) for the duration of the program (forever in embedded systems) Globals also make for less maintainable and more fragile programs.

If you only need the data inside a function, declare it there.  There is almost no penalty (initialization only) and the used space is automatically returned when the function returns as local variables are placed on the stack as are passed parameters.